# Powershell run from Python returns copyright information

Tags: powershell, python

I am executing a powershell script using python subprocess module.

```
subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe","-ExecutionPolicy","bypass","-file","kishore_test.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

When I am executing, Powershell script returns copyright information instead of actual output. So I would like to know , why am getting the output and how to rectify that.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unclear syntax `{Powershell script}`.

Comment: The script which am passing to subprocess module

Comment: Please [edit] the question and share _exact_ syntax you are using (please no metasymbols).

Comment: I have edited the question.Please check it now

Comment: Check `….communicate()` (`communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdout, stderr)`;  I'd guess that `….communicate()[1]` will return something like _"The argument 'kishore_test.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. …"_)

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(` is not powershell. what language are you ACTUALLY running?

Comment: Am using python script to run powershell script

Comment: You can ask Python programming questions on [so].